# How do I set an 'active' class to a menu item using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I wanted to set `class="active"` for the current active page but I couldn't get it to work. I keep getting the same error each time I included `<?php echo ($page == 'home') ? 'class="current"' : '';?>` in my anchor  and listing tags:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'home' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Users\Standard\Desktop\Test\includes\top.php on line 18

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong at the moment... I been researching and searching for the answer for the past 3 hours but still can't solve it. I just keep getting syntax errors. :(

This is my current code:

```
<?php
echo '
    <div class="top-nav-bg">
        <div class="top-nav container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="top-nav sixteen columns">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a <?php echo ($page == 'home') ? 'class="active"' : '';?> href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/our-services/">Our Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <ul>
                </div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
' ; >?
```

It's being included in my index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>

    <?php include ('/includes/header.php'); ?>

    <title>Home - Test</title>

  </head>
  <body id="homepage">

    <?php $page = 'home'; include ('/includes/top.php') ;?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting should make it clear. You should escape the `'` around `home`.

Comment: The superfluous <?php tags inside existing php tags are the issue here. Escaping the quotes won't fix that

Comment: quite a few syntax errors here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're already inside PHP, so your `<?php echo` isn't necessary. should just be:

```
<?php
echo '
    <div class="top-nav-bg">
        <div class="top-nav container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="top-nav sixteen columns">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a '.($page == 'home') ? 'class="active"' : ''.' href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/our-services/">Our Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <ul>
                </div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
' ; 
?>
```

Comment: this `>?` needs tending to.

Comment: Thanks! My page is empty now though, only showing class=active on the top of the page. I've changed it to '.($page == "home" ? "active" : "").' and it's now showing active inside my anchor tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't have rep to comment so will answer.

You're only outputing one variable so you don't need to have all that html inside php.
Plus by taking it out you won't have to worry about striping `'` or `"`.
Also if you're using a nice IDE/editor, you get better syntax highlighting.

Here's how you can do it in a cleaner way:

```
<div class="top-nav-bg">
    <div class="top-nav container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="top-nav sixteen columns">
                <ul>
                    <li><a <?= ($page === 'home') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?> href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/our-services/">Our Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/products/">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
                <ul>
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the use of `<?=`, this is shorthand for `<?php echo`.
Only php 5.4+ will accept them so use `<?php echo` if you're unsure it may be a problem.